# Página em PHP só com autorização de IP

Tags: php

Olá, queria saber como cria uma página que só pode entrar com autorização de IP, se puderem me mandar uma base dela agradeço

Comment: Poste o que você já tentou fazer.

Comment: Como assim? Só um determinado ip é que pode ver a página?

Comment: Sim, zekk ainda não tentei pois não sei fazer, mas é tipo uma página que só entra determinado IP

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/122561/4793